# Une question à propos de l'usage du pronom "y" comme COI

Tags: grammaire

Quelqu'un m'a indiqué qu'on peut souvent trouver des substitutions comme celles-ci:

> Je pense à toi.
> J'y pense.

Mais pourquoi la suivante n'existe-t-elle pas?

> Je commence à comprendre.
> J'y commence.

Comment: Il s'agit d'une locution verbale plutôt qu'un verbe avec un COD.

Comment: J'y commence would mean Je commence par là. That's where I begin.

Answer (score 2):

*J'**y** pense* signifie *je pense **à ça***. Le pronom ***y*** remplace un complément d'objet indirect.

*J'**y** commence* signifie *je commence **là***. L'adverbe ***y*** remplace le lieu dont on parle : *Je commence à cet endroit*.

Seul le [français parlé dans la région lyonnaise](https://francaisdenosregions.com/2016/09/01/le-y-dit-savoyard-laisse-je-vais-y-faire-y-manger-y-prendre/) permet une interprétation plus large de ce *Y*.

Si on souhaite absolument utiliser un pronom pour remplacer "à comprendre", on peut éventuellement dire :

> Je **le** commence.

Ici, le sens est *Je commence quelque chose*, et ce "quelque chose" est *à comprendre*. C'est néanmoins très peu idiomatique et on entendra plutôt simplement *Je commence* sous entendant *à (le) comprendre*.

Answer (score 1):

En français, comme en espagnol, il existe des cas dans lesquels on ajoute **à** ou **de** à l'infinitif suivant un autre verbe. Par exemple, « je viens d'y aller », « je commençais à (ou d') apprendre ce qu'ils disaient. » Dans ces cas, il est mieux de penser à **à** ou **de** comme une partie de l'infinitif.

Puis, on n'a pas besoin de dire **y**. On dit : « je l'commence. »

Comment: Merci beaucoup! Alors, est-ce qu'on peut dire à la fois "je commence à..." et je commence de..."?

Comment: @Caroline *Commencer de + infinitif* est très rare. C'est une forme que l'on trouve surtout dans la bouche d'apprenants. Leurs enseignants vont probablement la corriger. On la rencontre quand même un peu, mais c'est alors surtout une forme soutenue et littéraire, essentiellement à l'écrit et très rarement au présent.

Comment: Usage commun chez nous au sud de Que'bec: on dit << je commence 'a ...>> . Mais on entend de temps en temps expressions comme <<On perd patience! Commence pas de gueller  ou ton p'ere va devoir te punir!>>